# insert and update to different tables in one click with VB

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am trying to create a button that will save the data and update the data on the other table at the same time.(i'm using mysql workbench)

i have the code that will insert the data but currently stuck in the updating part.

the table for inserting is "ngpmain" and the table that needs to be updated are "ngpsites" and "ngpplanters"

this is my code for the insertion..

```js
Try
                Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO ngpmain (CENRO) values ('" + combobox2.selecteditem + "')", connection)
                Dim myDatatable As New DataTable
                myAdapter.Fill(myDatatable)
                MsgBox("The data has been added.")
                clearfields()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                connection.Dispose()
            End Try
```

Comment: To save changes from a `DataTable` to a database you call `Update` on your data adapter.  You need to have set the `InsertCommand` in order to insert new rows and the `UpdateCommand` to update existing rows.  There are lots of examples around.  Those examples pretty much all insert and update to the same table as they select from but that's not a requirement.  You can provide whatever SQL you like so there's nothing to stop you specifying different tables in your INSERT and UPDATE commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a Procedure that will Insert and Update your tables and 
Call to Procedure from VB.
Something Like This

PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateFields]

```
(
@ColumnName nvarchar (50),
@FormID int
)
```

as

```
if exists (select * from Fields Where FormID=@FormID)
Update FieldsIntegration set [ColumnName] = @ColumnName Where FormID=@FormID 
else
insert into FieldsIntegration (ColumnName) values (@ColumnName)
RETURN
```